# Sentinel value does not exit while loop

Tags: java

// In the following program, initally when the user is greeted with the instructions he can simply enter the sentinel to exit the while loop, however, when you get the result of tickets you wish to buy, pressing 999 does not exit the program

```
import java.io.*;

public class ManyTickets
{

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
  String userInput;
  String userInput2;
  int intInput = 0;
  int intInput2 = 0;
  double total = 0.00;
  BufferedReader ageInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  try{
    System.out.println("Please enter your age, or press '999' to exit.");
    userInput = ageInput.readLine();
    intInput = Integer.parseInt (userInput);
    while (intInput != 999)
    {
      if (intInput < 0 || intInput > 110)
        System.out.println("Invalid entry, or your age seems a bit too high to enter buy these tickets");
      else if (intInput <= 12)
      {
        total = total + 6;
        System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is " + total);
      }
      else if (intInput <= 64)
      {
        total = total + 11;
        System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is " + total);  
      }
      else
      {
        total = total + 8;
        System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is $" + total);
      }
      System.out.println("So far, your tickets cost is: $" + total  );
      System.out.print("Would you like to buy more tickets? You can buy up to 1 more ticket per customer! If no press 999 to exit");
      userInput = ageInput.readLine();
      intInput2 = Integer.parseInt (userInput);  
      }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
       System.out.println("Please restart the program, and enter an integer instead!");
    }
  } 
  {
    double total = 0.0;
    System.out.println("Thank you,  The total cost for the ticket is: $" + total);
    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything after the user enters 999. Break the loop when its 999 as below,

```
intInput2 = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

if (intInput2 == 999) {
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using two different variables, `intInput` and `intInput2`.  I don't see why you need the second one (right before the catch block).  Just reuse `intInput`, which is the one being checked against the sentinel value in your while loop.

Comment: The previous answer already worked, but to add on to your answer, i already tried that before posting is, the thing is the sentinel value worked, but there was a problem the calculations didn't whenever i pressed a key to continue for the peoples ages greater then 12 and less then 64, and greater then 64 the program add 6 dollars each time to the output instead of what it was sopposed to add, either being 8 dollars or 11